# Error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, array

Es algo sencillo que estoy haciendo solo intento pedir un tamaño de un vector y luego llenarlo en java. Lo quise hacer como practica sin embargo al momento de correr el programa me mostraba error. Quisiera saber si alguien me podría ayudar. Este es mi codigo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Diga el tamaño del vector: ");
    int tam = sc.nextInt();
    int num[] = new int[tam];

    for (int i = 1; i <=tam; i++) {
        System.out.print("Ingrese dato: ");
        num[i]=sc.nextInt();

    }

    System.out.println("Mostrando los datos: ");
           System.out.println();
           for (int i = 0; i < tam;) {
               System.out.println(num[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Si alguna solución te ha servido, recuerda darle a la palomita y aceptarla, por el bien de la comunidad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La verdad es que se ven varios fallos.

> El Primero:

Es que los índices en los Arrays empiezan por el 0 'Este sería la primera posición. El primer bucle for quedaría así..

```
for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
    System.out.print("Ingrese dato: ");
    num[i]=sc.nextInt();

}
```

> El Segundo:

A la hora de imprimir el resultado, no vas incrementando el valor de la i, y se te queda en un bucle infinito imprimiendo el valor de la 1ª posición. Este bucle for quedaría así:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
    System.out.println(num[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para mostrar los resultados hazlo asi:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=tam;i++) {
           System.out.println(num[i]);
}
```

El problema es que estás accediendo a mas elementos que el tamaño del array, por ejemplo tu array solo tiene 5 y tu estas accediendo a un sexto elemento que no existe porque tu array solo tiene capacidad para 5.

Comment: entenido gracias @Mariano

Answer (score 1):

El error de ta porque intentas acceder a elementos que no existen fuera del array en el `for`, y en concreto, en la sentencia `num[i] = sc.nextInt();` por la condición `i <= tam`.

Si el array tiene n elementos, estás intentando acceder al elemento inmediatamente siguiente al último, elemento que no existe, por lo que salta una excepción que indica que el índice está fuera del rango de índices del array.

Esto ocurre porque en Java, así como en la mayoría de lenguajes de programación (no todos), los índices de un array, o incluso de una colección ordenada (como una lista secuencial), empiezan en el 0 y acaban en n-1, si el array tiene n elementos.

Por ejemplo, si tenemos un array con dos elementos, los índices para acceder serán el 0 para el primero, y el 1 para el segundo.

```
int[] dos = new int[2];    // Se crea un array de tamaño 2

dos[0] = 1;    // dos[0] hace referencia al primer elemento
dos[1] = 2;    // dos[1] hace referencia al segundo y último elemento

dos[2] = 3;    // error: un array con dos elementos no tiene tercer elemento
```

Por lo tanto, cuando hagas un recorrido sobre un array de tamaño n, lo tienes que hacer de 0 a n-1.

```
int[] numeros = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    numeros[i] = i;
```

En este caso, `i` tomará valores entre 0 y n-1 (n iteraciones), por lo que no se saldrá del rango de índices del array. Fíjate que he puesto `i < 10` y no `i <= 10`, porque de esta forma, la última iteración será cuando `i` valga 9 (los índices van de 0 a 9 en un array de 10 elementos).

Lo más correcto, sin embargo, no es utilizar literales, sino hacerlo haciendo referencia al tamaño del array, sobre todo si se crea en base al tamaño que el usuario diga. Por ejemplo.

```
int[] numeros = new int[/* tamaño */];
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++)
    numeros[i] = i;
```

También se puede hacer un recorrido de 1 a n, pero al acceder al array, se le resta 1 al índice para que vaya de 0 a n-1.

```
int[] numeros = new int[/* tamaño */];
for (int i = 1; i <= numeros.length; i++)
    numeros[i - 1] = i;
```

En este caso, sí que se pone `i <= tam`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que las computadoras empiezan a contar desde el numero cero, por lo que debes restar menos uno (-1) al indice del `array`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Diga el tamaño del vector: ");
    int tam = sc.nextInt();
    int num[] = new int[tam];

    for (int i = 1; i < tam - 1; i++) {
        System.out.print("Ingrese dato: ");
        num[i]=sc.nextInt();

    }
    System.out.println("Mostrando los datos: ");
           System.out.println();
           for (int i = 0; i < tam - 1; i++) {
               System.out.println(num[i]);
    }

}
```