# error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException al querer meter datos a una matriz en java

Tags: java

Estoy recibiendo este error al compilar mi programa en java: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

El codigo donde me da error es este:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Main mn=new Main();
        char op='s';
        int cont=0;
        int casos;
        int recuperados;
        int muertes;
        int totalcasos=0;
        int totalrecuperados=0;
        int totalmuertes=0;
        int casosactivos=0;
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        int matriz[][]=new int[cont][10];
        do{
            
            System.out.println("Ingrese numero de casos confirmados: ");
                casos = scan.nextInt();
                matriz[cont][0]=casos;
                totalcasos += casos;
            cont++;
           System.out.println("Quiere continuar ingresando datos? (s/n)");
           op=scan.next().charAt(0);
        }while(op=='s');
}
```

Y asi cuando pido otros datos y los quiero poner de la forma matriz[cont][columna].

El cont es para las filas y pues para la columna pongo el numero de la columna que necesito. Me di cuenta que al parecer el error es con las filas osea el contador pero la verdad no se que puedo estar haciendo mal.

Comment: cont es cero según tu código, así que matriz se inicializa de 0 x 10. Claro que te va a dar indexoutofbounds. O cambias la inicialización de la matriz o usas una estructura de datos diferente

Comment: @Alfabravo pero es que necesito que la matriz tenga filas asi con el contador para representar diferentes ciclos , intente poner el cont++ al principio antes de pedir los datos pero tampoco funcionaba, y cambiando el cont a 1 y poniendo matriz[cont-1][columna] me deja meter datos par el primer ciclo pero ya luego me da el mismo error

Comment: Te estás equivocando en grande. Lo que dice @Alfabravo es cierto, tu error es darle el valor 0 a tu matriz. Tienes que entender que tu matriz **no es dinámica**, así que si lo inicializas con cero *entonces siempre será cero y no podrás añadir ningún dato dentro*. Tienes que darle un valor máximo para solucionar tu problema.

Comment: @VíctorHugoTiradoUmm ya veo, efectivamente me acabo de dar cuenta, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145008/error-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)